# Hibernate validates wrong schema

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

The actual schema connected and used for validation is “sbusdemo” but it checks other available schemas for validation, displaying “missing column…” error message in console.

This happened only in few PCs’.

**Error Message**

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
15:57:13 ERROR o.s.w.c.ContextLoader: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/E:/shashidhar/work/Eclipse%20workspace/Sbus-Demo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ritebooks-web/WEB-INF/lib/ritebooks-repository-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-repository.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id in sakila.country
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699) [catalina.jar:8.5.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165) [catalina.jar:8.5.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412) [catalina.jar:8.5.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402) [catalina.jar:8.5.45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id in sakila.country
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1338) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564) ~[spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/E:/shashidhar/work/Eclipse%20workspace/Sbus-Demo/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ritebooks-web/WEB-INF/lib/ritebooks-repository-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-repository.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id in sakila.country
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id in sakila.country
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1338)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 21 more

Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ritebooks-web] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [ritebooks-web] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8998"]
Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 25, 2020 3:57:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 117646 ms
```

Following is the configuration

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan"
            value="com.mactec.riteerp.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform"
                    value="${hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect}" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="showSql"
                    value="${hibernate.show_sql:false}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <util:map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect"
                    value="${hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
                    value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto:validate}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql"
                    value="${hibernate.show_sql:false}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql"
                    value="${hibernate.format_sql:false}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments"
                    value="${hibernate.use_sql_comments:false}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics"
                    value="${hibernate.generate_statistics:false}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy"
                    value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
                <entry key="javax.persistence.transactionType"
                    value="RESOURCE_LOCAL" />
                <entry key="javax.persistence.validation.factory"
                    value-ref="validator" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- MySql DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="com.mactec.dbcp.ManagedBasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="${db.driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver}" />
        <property name="url"
            value="${db.url:jdbc:mysql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:3306}/${db.name:riteerp}?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username:root}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password:root}" />
        <property name="validationQuery"
            value="${db.pool.validation.query}" />

        <property name="maxActive" value="${db.pool.maxActive:200}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="${db.pool.maxWait:2000}" />

        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

**Properties...**

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.show_sql=false
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.pool.validation.query=select 1;
db.host=127.0.0.1
db.port=3306
db.name=sbusdemo
db.username=root
db.password=root db.url=jdbc:mysql://${db.host:localhost}:${db.port:3306}/${db.name:sbusdemo}? 
        useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```

**Versions used:**

- hibernate-core 4.3.7.FINAL,
- hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.7.FINAL,
- hibernate-validator 4.3.1.FINAL,
- spirng-core 4.1.1.RELEASE,
- MySQL Server 5.7
- mysql-connector-java 5.1.6

Comment: You expect an answer without knowing/seeing your configuration?

Comment: Do not post the error as image post it as text instead

Comment: My bad. I've edited the post with required information. Please read the same again @M.Deinum

Comment: Why the complexity in both XML and the properties for resolving defaults? Beats the p urpose imho. Is the connection made to the proper DB/schema? Also do you have a schema mentioned in your entities declaration?

Comment: Just in case for defaults. The schema name and respective schema entity are absolutely correct. As mentioned in the post, this configuration works fine in other computer with same system configuration and same tools installed. I've tried re-installing eclipse, MySQL suite and re-importing m2 repository. Yet i face the same issue @M.Deinum

Comment: No. None of the entities have schema mentioned in their declaration.

Comment: @Sainath did you find a solution or at least an explanation to this?
I got the same issue just now, while updating from mysql-connector-j 5.1.47 to 8.0.22. Maybe something to do with Hibernate’s Mysql dialect ?

Comment: See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9607